# Finding a pattern within an image

Tags: java, android, image, comparison, pattern-matching

I have been searching the web for a bit on image comparison but couldn't find any definitive answers. What I want to do is see if a certain pattern exists within a larger image. Is there a nice way of doing this in java (specifically to be implemented on an android device)?

Comment: You can use OpenCV library.You ll have to use NDK for that .there are samples as well that might be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are ways of doing this although you will have to look into JavaCV which is the google conversion of the OpenCV libraries.  Specifically you will want to look into the template-matching APIs.

There are a couple resources that should help you:
http://myrobotlab.org/node/104

http://code.google.com/p/myrobotlab/source/browse/trunk/myrobotlab/src/org/myrobotlab/image/OpenCVFilterMatchTemplate.java

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FastMatchTemplate